# How replace all these "if...elif...else" statements with something more concise?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, if-statement

Is there a way to reduce the amount of `elif` things in my statement? In [another question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71592516/how-to-make-my-second-while-true-statement-work-the-same-as-my-first-one/71592810#71592810) someone said that my code suffered from redundancy and it definitely does. I'm relatively new to python and coding in general and when I look things up it's always kind of hard to understand.

This is the block of code I'm talking about:

(If needed I can post the rest of the code)

```
if (random_mon_name.lower()=='normal'):
    rangen_mon_name = random.choice(mon_name_type_NORMAL)
    break
elif (random_mon_name.lower()=='fire'):
    rangen_mon_name = random.choice(mon_name_type_FIRE)
    break
elif (random_mon_name.lower()=='water'):
    rangen_mon_name = random.choice(mon_name_type_WATER)
    break
elif (random_mon_name.lower()=='grass'):
    rangen_mon_name = random.choice(mon_name_type_GRASS)
    break
elif (random_mon_name.lower()=='electric'):
    rangen_mon_name = random.choice(mon_name_type_ELECTRIC)
    break
elif (random_mon_name.lower()=='ice'):
    rangen_mon_name = random.choice(mon_name_type_ICE)
    break
elif (random_mon_name.lower()=='fighting'):
    rangen_mon_name = random.choice(mon_name_type_FIGHTING)
    break
elif (random_mon_name.lower()=='poison'):
    rangen_mon_name = random.choice(mon_name_type_POISON)
    break
elif (random_mon_name.lower()=='ground'):
    rangen_mon_name = random.choice(mon_name_type_GROUND)
    break
elif (random_mon_name.lower()=='flying'):
    rangen_mon_name = random.choice(mon_name_type_FLYING)
    break
elif (random_mon_name.lower()=='psychic'):
    rangen_mon_name = random.choice(mon_name_type_PSYCHIC)
    break
elif (random_mon_name.lower()=='bug'):
    rangen_mon_name = random.choice(mon_name_type_BUG)
    break
elif (random_mon_name.lower()=='ghost'):
    rangen_mon_name = random.choice(mon_name_type_GHOST)
    break
elif (random_mon_name.lower()=='rock'):
    rangen_mon_name = random.choice(mon_name_type_ROCK)
    break
elif (random_mon_name.lower()=='dark'):
    rangen_mon_name = random.choice(mon_name_type_DARK)
    break
elif (random_mon_name.lower()=='dragon'):
    rangen_mon_name = random.choice(mon_name_type_DRAGON)
    break
elif (random_mon_name.lower()=='steel'):
    rangen_mon_name = random.choice(mon_name_type_STEEL)
    break
elif (random_mon_name.lower()=='fairy'):
    rangen_mon_name = random.choice(mon_name_type_FAIRY)
    break
else:
    print("You didn't actually enter a type.\nTry Again.")
```

Comment: Use a single `dict` to hold the various lists of monsters, not a bunch of individually named lists. `d = {'normal': mon_name_type_NORMAL, 'fire': mon_name_type_FIRE}`, etc.

Comment: Are you going to define `mon_name_type_...` in any case for other reasons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The root cause of there being so much redundancy in this code is the huge number of variables you have to manage.

Whenever you have a bunch of individual variables that all hold the same kind of data, like `mon_name_type_FIRE` and `mon_name_type_WATER` (I assume these are lists of names associated with that attack type), it's a strong clue that you should instead put them into a collection, like a dictionary, or a list.  Not only does this reduce the number of variables to keep track of in your code, it makes it possible to access those values dynamically rather than with a ton of copy+pasted code.

For example, if you took all your different `mon`s and put them in a `dict` that's keyed by their attack type, *instead of* creating all the `mon_name_type_WHATEVER` variables:

```
mon_by_type = {
    "fire": ["charmander", "charmeleon", "charizard"],
    "water": ["squirtle", "wartortle", "blastoise"],
    # etc
}
```

you can now replace your giant `if`/`elif` chain with a single dictionary lookup:

```
try:
    random_mon = random.choice(mon_by_type[random_mon_name.lower()])
except KeyError:
    print("You didn't actually enter a type.  Try again.")
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot. Everything looks much more neater now, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest you to create a single `dict`, this way:

```
myDict = {}
myDict['ice'] = mon_name_type_ICE
# ...and so on
```

So that then you will access it with a small piece of code:

```
rangen_mon_name = random.choice(myDict[random_mon_name.lower()])
```

You can also add a `try`/`except` block to simulate your `else`:

```
try:
    rangen_mon_name = random.choice(myDict[random_mon_name.lower()])
except KeyError:
    print("You didn't actually enter a type.\nTry Again.")
```

Comment: That's how I would do it for sure. Might be cleaner to do an explicit declaration but otherwise I agree

Answer (score 1):

So far I like @Samwise's answer the best because it makes the code "[data-driven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-driven_programming)" because it not only eliminates all all those variables, it also make extending things trivial as well — but think it could be taken a little bit further by making the creation of the one dictionary itself also done that way. Here's what I mean:

```
from pprint import pprint
import random


MON_TYPE_NAMES = """\
    normal, Normodo, Normalia, Normew
    fire, Firaint, Heatoro, Flamala
    water, Splashoto, Oceatto, Puddlio
    grass, Weedevon, Grassimar, Leafadroon
    electric, Enetick, Electol, Litero
    ice, Snova, Icello, Colaggro
    fighting, Allphist, Lullakick, Bubblow
    poison, Poizase, Gunkamight, Aison
    ground, Groutal, Moundiflox, Umbron
    flying, Wingyu, Sparial, Flogun
    psychic, Mindswell, Thinkarva, Psymarine
    bug, Bugonite, Flyzaur, Mantile
    ghost, Phantini, Spirook, Tortasm
    rock, Storilot, Rocoalia, Sedite
    dark, Nolite, Dariotte, Nitrash
    dragon, Dracat, Wyveron, Randigon
    steel, Metalaze, Gearevo, Iromonora
    fairy, Faeream, Pixirola, Trixitrite
"""

# Create dictionary from mon type names.
name_to_choices = {v[0]: v[1:] for v in (line.replace(',', ' ').split()
                                    for line in MON_TYPE_NAMES.splitlines())}
pprint(name_to_choices, sort_dicts=False)
print()

# Select random mon name based on mon type.
random_mon_type = 'Ghost'
if not (choices := name_to_choices.get(random_mon_type.lower())):
    print("Unknown mon type")
else:
    rangen_mon_name = random.choice(choices)
    print(f'random {random_mon_type} name -> {rangen_mon_name}')
```

Comment: If you run this and inspect the output carefully, you'll find that some of the names got glued together, which is a good illustration of why building a data structure from a big blob of text can be hazardous -- you have to put in a lot more effort to make it typo-proof, especially if you want to be able to detect typos through static analysis instead of runtime errors.

Comment: @Samwise: I may have introduced errors via my text editor while reformatting data copied and pasted from the linked question (which was inconsistently formatted itself) — but that misses the point I was trying to make. Besides any error there may be are easily corrected in the one spot where the data exists — no textual data is typo-proof, regardless of it size.

Comment: @Samwise: I fixed the one line that wasn't formatted quite right and also made a minor change to the code that parses it and creates the dictionary so it would not be quite as picky about the kind of error that was causing the problem in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Construct a dictionary like `choices` below. Pass the attack value to `get_attack_values` and if the attack is in `choices`, pass the value, i.e. `mon_name_type_ICE` to the `random.choice()` function.

```
import random

choices = { 
        'ice': {'choice': 'mon_name_type_ICE'},
        'fire': { 'choice': 'mon_name_type_WATER'}
         }
       
def get_attack_value(attack):
    if attack in choices.keys():
        rangen_mon_name = random.choice(choices[attack]['choice'])
    else:
        print("You didn't actually enter a type.\nTry Again.")

get_attack_value('fire')
```

Comment: Don't loop through a dictionary to get a matching value, just do `choices[attack]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the variables like `mon_name_type_FIRE` in other areas of your code and you are able to create a "names" lookup or dictionary you will definitely want to do that. See answers by @FLAC-ZOSO and @samwise to get you started.

If however, you have all these "name" lists already defined and want to use the "appropriate" one, you might think about just getting them from `locals()` (or `globals())`.

```py
import random

## ------------------
## You have these pre-defined and want to keep them
## as distinct variables for some reason.
## ------------------
mon_name_type_NORMAL = ["Elf", "Human"]
mon_name_type_FIRE = ["Fire Dwarf", "Cinder Elf"]
## ------------------

## ------------------
## Use a "mob" class and locals() to find the appropriate matching
## list of mob names.
## ------------------
random_mon_name = "Fire"
rmn_key = f"mon_name_type_{random_mon_name.upper()}"
name_options = locals().get(rmn_key, ["**unnamed mob**"])
## ------------------

print(random.choice(name_options))
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Scream

Comment: IMO generating variable names on the fly is close to as bad of an idea as creating variables on the fly is.

Answer (score -1):

This seems like you would benefit from throwing all of these into a data structure like a dictionary. Since you're just setting values to other values with perfect 1:1 mapping a dictionary was literally made for this.

```
random_mon_name_dict = {'normal': random.choice(mon_name_type_NORMAL), 'bug', random.choice(mon_name_type_BUG)}
```

But for all of them obviously.

Am I understanding correctly?